Handling large graphs with pyvis
I'm trying to make a graph with 1500 nodes (later on, they should be like 10 millions...). I used pyvis because it makes graphs readable on a large scale (with networkx it looks very bad).
But when I only have 1500 nodes and physics activated, it takes 2 minutes to load (the html). And, when I disable physics I get a weird result like this : 
(notice that most of the nodes are in the center at the same place so even when zooming its unreadable).
When it looks like this with physics 
So I wonder if I could have a nice looking graph without physics or if there were ways to make the generating process with physics faster
Heres my code for exemple, it genereate the graph from a JSON and apply a size to nodes based on connections in python :
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
from pyvis.network import Network

def create_from_json(json_file):
    G = nx.DiGraph(directed=True)
    with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    for key, values in data.items():
        for element in values:
            G.add_edge(str(key), str(element)) 
    
    node_degree = dict(G.degree())
    for key in data.keys():
        if key in node_degree:
            del node_degree[key]
    
    scale = 10  
    node_size = {node: scale * degree for node, degree in node_degree.items()}
    nx.set_node_attributes(G, node_size, 'size')
    
    G2 = Network(height="1500px", width="1900px", bgcolor="#222222", font_color="white", directed=True)
    G2.from_nx(G)
    G2.toggle_physics(False)
    G2.show_buttons(True)
    G2.show("wikimap.html", notebook=False)

create_from_json("dico_unique.json")


import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
from pyvis.network import Network

def create_from_json(json_file):
    G = nx.DiGraph(directed=True)
    with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    for key, values in data.items():
        for element in values:
            G.add_edge(str(key), str(element)) 

    layout = nx.spring_layout(G)
    
    G2 = Network(height="1500px", width="1900px", bgcolor="#222222", font_color="white", directed=True)
    G2.from_nx(G, default_node_size=30)

    for node in G2.nodes:
        node_id = node["id"]
        if node_id in layout:
            node["x"], node["y"] = layout[node_id][0]*1000, layout[node_id][1]*1000

    G2.toggle_physics(False)
    G2.show_buttons(filter_=['physics'])
    G2.show("wikimap.html", notebook=False)


Thanks for this answer, this solutions works and create a more readable graph while not being super long to make. I'm still going to let the question open to see what other people are going to say. Also, the graph's shape is not exactly what I wanted (but I don't really mind).

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
